# calling mysql database query with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to query a database but I don't want it to do it when the page loads. I want it to query during execution of a javascript function. How do I do this? Below is my code.
I have tried just adding php tags in the middle of the function and calling *loadAvailableReservations()* but it returns with an error even when I close the script tags.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "fbla";

function loadAvailableReservations() {
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT id, name, date FROM availableReservations";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<br> id: ". $row["id"]. " - Name: ". $row["name"]. " " . $row["date"] . "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
}
?>


<html>
    </head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 298px)' href="css/unsuported.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" media='screen and (min-width: 298px) and (max-width: 552px)' href="css/small.css" />
        <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 552px) and (max-width: 806px)' href='css/medium.css' />
        <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 806px) and (max-width: 9999999px)' href='css/regular.css' />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header-div">
            <a href="index.html" id="header-div-a-regular">Mountain Springs Family Entertainment Center</a>
            <a href="index.html" id="header-div-a-small">Mountain Springs FEC</a>
            <div id="header-div-menubutton">
                <hr id="hr-1">
                <hr id="hr-2">
                <hr id="hr-3">
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#specials/events" onclick="return specialsEventsAppend()">Specials/Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#bookit" onclick="return bookitAppend()">Book it!</a></li>
                <li><a href="#schedule" onclick="return scheduleAppend()">Schedule</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="mobileMenu-div" style="display:none">
            <center>
                <ul id="mobileMenuUl">
                    <li id="ulfirstli"><a href="#about" onclick="return specialsEventsAppend()">Specials/Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#bookit" onclick="return bookitAppend()">Book it!</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#schedule" onclick="return scheduleAppend()">Schedule</a></li>
                </ul>
            </center>
        </div>
        <div id="maincontent-div">
            <p id="unsuported-p">Sorry but this screen resolution is unsuported :/<p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $('#header-div-menubutton').live('click', function(event) {
            toggleMobileMenuDiv();
        });

        function toggleMobileMenuDiv() {
            $('#mobileMenu-div').slideToggle("fast");
        }
    });
    function mobileMenu() {
        var div = document.getElementById('mobileMenu-div');
    }
    function specialsEventsAppend() {
        var div = document.getElementById('maincontent-div');
        //clears everything in the div
        div.innerHTML = "";
        //puts the content into the div
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + 'Extra stuff';
    }
    function bookitAppend() {
        var div = document.getElementById('maincontent-div');
        div.innerHTML = "";
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<center><div id="bookit-div"><p> January 20<sup>th<sup><div id="bookit-list"></div></div><center><center><div id="bookit-div"><p> January 21<sup>st<sup><div id="bookit-list"></div></div><center><center><div id="bookit-div"><p> January 22<sup>nd<sup><div id="bookit-list"></div></div><center><center><div id="bookit-div"><p> January 23<sup>rd<sup><div id="bookit-list"></div></div><center>';
    }

    function scheduleAppend() {
        var div = document.getElementById('maincontent-div');
        div.innerHTML = "";
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + '<center><h3>Days available for reservations</h3></center><center><table><tr><th>Day</th><th>Time</th></tr><tr><td>Sunday</td><center><td>Closed</td></center></tr><td>Monday</td><center><td>8:00-11:00</td></center></tr><tr><td>Tuesday</td><center><td>8:00-11:00</td></center></tr><tr><td>Wensday</td><center><td>8:00-11:00</td></center></tr><tr><td>Thursday</td><center><td>8:00-11:00</td></cetner></tr><tr><td>Friday</td><center><td>10:00-11:00</td></center></tr></table></center>';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I think you might want to consider sending an AJAX request to your php code (ideally a separate file). I don't think you can directly call PHP functions from JavaScript like this.

Answer (score 0):

Break the code in two files:
eg: index.html
... add all html here except php code
index.php
add all php code here and right after your function call it eg: loadReservationPlaces();
Then in index.html load jquery in the bottom, immediately above  tag (will be easy and less code to write)

```
<script type="javascript" src="pathToYourjQueryLibrary/jQuery.hs"><script>
```

Then in your js script call index.php with $.ajax():

> $.ajax({
>        method: "POST",
>        url: "index.php" }).done(function( msg ) {
>       console.log(msg); });

Check your browser js console

Comment: this doesnt query anything for some reason all its doing is the console message

Comment: Right, it is in console because of console.log(). You have to fetch your data in your DOM with a js method. Make a div element in your html code like this: <div id="mydiv"></div> Modify the code as: ...done(function(msg){ var msg = msg; $("mydiv").html(msg)   }); If you don't want to fetch your data at load time, bind the ajax method to an particularly event, like $(element).on("click", function() { $.ajax( //yourcodehere);})

Comment: $.ajax({ method: "POST", url: "querydb.php" }).done(function(msg){ var msg = msg; $("maincontent-div").html(msg) });

this is what i have so far but for somereason nothing is happening and there arent any errors

Comment: You should tell to ajax what format will be the callback success result. There are four cases: html, json, text and auto guess (default). So if you are echo some html in querydb.php you must add "type":"html" in your ajax preparation object

Comment: im sorry i dont know how to do that i have never used ajax before